# how to reduce "URL Fetch calls" refresh rate in GoogleSheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, refresh, urlfetch, custom-function

I have a Spreadsheets that collects data from external JSON API to form a database, I know this JSON API updates 1 time a day, this my spreadsheets make about 500 "URL Fetch calls" to fill the whole database, because it is 1 call per line and the database has about 500 lines, in addition, I also do the "File > Share > Public on web" mode and I know that there is an audience of 50~100 people who access this page.

According to Google's rules, external data is limited to 20,000 per day, as stated on this page, in the "URL Fetch calls" line:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

If I check the option "automatically republish when changes are made" I notice that at the bottom of the page it shows the information "Updated automatically every 5 minutes", but with this option checked, the limit of the "URL Fetch calls" happens in the middle of the day exceeds.

So I have some questions:

- spreadsheets make 500 calls every 5min. even if the data is not changed? if yes then i have 144,000 calls per day so is there any way to change this time to 5min. for 12hour?
- by changing ImportJSON.gs is there any way to make this refresh rate be reduced to just 1 or 2 times a day?

here is the function I use to collect the JSON data:
https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/master/ImportJSON.gs

At the moment I haven't tried anything to solve it, as I don't have much knowledge about this ImportJSON. I expect some code change in ImportJSON function or GoogleSheets config or something like that.

Comment: Don't use custom function. Use triggers instead.

Comment: Have you researched the API to see if you can get pages of data rather than 1 line at a time?

Comment: @TheWizEd yes, unfortunately it is not possible

Comment: @TheMaster sorry for my lack of knowledge, but what triggers are these?

Comment: Time based triggers. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Cache Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache) to make your custom function call external services less often. See [Apps Script Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_the_cache_service) for sample code. *I am not affiliated with any product, website or book related with the Cache Service or the sample code, and I am not employed by any company that is so affiliated.*

If all data rows can be retrieved in one go, get them all with one call instead of duplicating your spreadsheet formula 500 times.

Comment: If you want to recommend your own product or website or your own posts elsewhere, there are some [guidelines in place](/help/promotion) for doing so. Following them will help you avoid giving the impression that you're spamming. Please [edit] your post to explicitly state your affiliation. (If you're not actually affiliated, it may be worth mentioning that as well.)

Comment: Hrmh. Not promoting my product, my website, my book or my job. The _answer_ is to use the Cache service. I posted a sample code link to show how to use that service. Cannot simply paste the code here as it is under the Apache license while this site uses CC BY-SA.

Comment: I didn't ask you to post the code here. If the code(in second link) is written by you, you can disclose it that it is written by you. If not, it's still better to explicitly state your affiliation, when sharing links outside official documentation.

Comment: @doubleunary Thanks for the answer, I've been testing this CacheService method, but I realized that it has a limit of 50,000 characters, and every JSON I get has a lot more than that.
Error
"Error: Text result of getRssFeed is longer than the limit of 50000 characters."
:(

Comment: @doubleunary Oops, my mistake, 50k Chars is the limit of each GoogleSheets cell, disregard my comment above, hehe